Method to Utilize NodeJS Array from Sequelize into the Script Tag of a Pug Template
So I am having an issue with figuring out how to get the variable that is passed from NodeJS into my Pug Template into a variable within the Pug Template's Script tag. The issue is that it is a Sequelize Object, and the front-end JavaScript doesn't recognize it as a basic object. Since I am most of the way through my project, I don't want to force it to return a raw object since most of my application is built around how it returns the Sequelize Object itself.
So here is my code:
script.
    let keys = '#{nodejskeys}'

This in itself returns just the Sequelize Object, but I need the array within it to parse on the front-end. Any thoughts?
I tried utilizing for-loops to no avail.

I apologize, I figured it out. To anyone looking to utilize a variable like this you can use mapping to break down the Sequelize Object. I got it to work by using the below method:
let keys = []
keys.push('#{nodejskeys.map(key => {return key.key})')

This allowed me to map through the array and return just the attributes I needed to form the front-end JS array.
I hope this helps someone in the future.
